# wxpython Choice key down event won't run

Tags: python, wxpython

i am using wxpython and wx.Choice.
I Tried to bind it but it don't reach the function and don't work, whys that?
Also when i do focus at this Choice (and he already binded), it do run the function but twice.
Why's that and how i can change it?

```
 Select=wx.Choice(parent, choices=SectorList,pos=pos,size=(100,25))
 Select.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN,self.OnInputCharPressSelect)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing since you don't have a small runnable sample. Here is an example:

```
import wx


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent): 
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        txt = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.choice_widget = wx.Choice(self, choices=['a', 'b', 'c'])
        self.choice_widget.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnInputCharPressSelect)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(txt, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        main_sizer.Add(self.choice_widget, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)

    def OnInputCharPressSelect(self, event):
        print('OnInputCharPressSelect fired')

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Choices')

        panel = MyPanel(self)

        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

When I TAB into the `Choice` widget from the `TextCtrl` widget, the bound event handler does not fire, which is correct. It also won't fire if I select an item using the mouse. To do that, you would need to bind the `Choice` widget to `EVT_CHOICE`.

To get the `OnInputCharPressSelect` to fire, you must have the `Choice` widget highlighted (i.e. selected) and then press a key on your keyboard. This will cause the handler to be fired once per key press.

I tested this code on Window 7 with wxPython 4.0.0b2 and Python 3.6.